# Tailwind Content Overlapping Screen

Tags: tailwind-css

No matter what I seem to try, I cannot align some content in a nav bar in the center of the screen (oh the irony I know!)

```
# app.vue
<template>
  <header>
    <ContactBar />
  </header>
</template>
```

```
# ContactBar.vue
<template>
  <nav class="bg-neutral-900 w-100">
    <div class="mx-auto p-4 max-w-7xl text-zinc-300">
      <p>abc</p>
    </div>
  </nav>
</template>
```

Output:

[image: very off center positioning]

What am I doing wrong here? :(

Answer (score 0):

In the ContactBar.vue you should change `w-100` (which is not a standard tailwind class btw) with `w-full`. Then you need to replace the `max-w-7xl` on the child by `min-w-max w-[80rem]`. The `w-[80rem]` is the replacement of the 7xl max width, which also is 80rem.

See playground example:

https://play.tailwindcss.com/VHSBUxiMx5